# Project Approval using InfoPath form and workflows

Tags: 2007, workflow

I have an InfoPath form embedded in a MOSS 2007 page. The form is for requesting approval for a project. The submit button submits the form data to a form library. That triggers a workflow to get approval for the request.

So far, my workflow uses the "Collect Data From User" action and the "Send and email" action. I configured data collection option so that there are two inputs: two radio buttons for approve/reject and a comment field. I built the email body and subject using dynamic strings and variables from the form data.

I would like this approval process to be simple for the person that does the approval. Ideally, they could see the information in one webpage, approve or reject it, write a comment explaining why it was approved or rejected and then click some sort of submit button.

I haven't found an easy solution like that, so I went with sending an email and creating a task.

There are a few problems with this method:

- The email that is sent when the task is assigned to the approver doesn't seem to be editable or have the option of being disabled (I don't want them to have a link to the XML for simplicity sake)
- The link from the "You have been assigned as task" email is small and does not take you directly to the page where you can click "Complete Task" (you have to click Edit Item from the linked page)
- The data and approval form are separated

Simplicity is key here. Thanks for any advice you can give.

Answer (score 2):

I have found it best to include the approval process as a section within the form. You can create views that make the form read only once it has been submitted for approval and send an email to the approver with a link to the form where they will have radio buttons and text fields as well for approval. I have tried different ways to approach this and this has always worked the best and kept all of the information efficiently  within the same form library.

Comment: How does that fit into the workflow? Do I link to a page with a web viewer and stick the infopath form in the web viewer? How can I link to the page and have the information grabbed from the right form data in the form library?

Comment: The link would be back to the form that was submitted. You would just create a section that would be hidden until after submit and then create an open rule that would switch to a read only view of everything else with the section revealed.